# macports mongod fails to start

Tags: mongodb, macports

I have installed mongodb using macports. I can run mongod from the terminal with

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /opt/local/var/db/mongodb
```

When I try to run it with:

```
sudo port load mongodb
```

mongod fails to start. The log file shows repeated attempts to start, each of them including the message

```
 info preallocateIsFaster couldn't run due to: couldn't open file /opt/local/var/db/mongodb/journal/tempLatencyTest for writing errno:13 Permission denied; returning false
```

There is no such file, but the directory exists. It is owned by root with group _mongo. Changing its ownership to _mongo resulted in other problems. I also tried

```
mongod --repair
```

and although that had fixed a problem with the lock file it isn't fixing this one. Help appreciated.

Comment: What user/group is your `mongod` running as? For MacPorts it looks like the user and group should both be `_mongo` (ref: [MacPorts](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/databases/mongodb/Portfile)). The error message you have suggests a permission problem; this should be unrelated to repairing the database.